# Submit button on form in react also checks other components form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I have a multiple form react application where I render each form based on the page the user is currently on (the index of page). I want the next button that retrieves the next component to also be a submit button.
The problem is the next button does change the index and hence render the next component but it immediately throws an error on the required field on the next rendered form. How can I prevent this ?

Here is how I render the components

```
<form>
    {statementArray[currentStepIndex]}

    <Buttons 
        currentStep={currentStepIndex}
        getNextStatement={getNextStatement} 
        next={next} 
        back={back} />
</form>
```

Also the *statementArray* is an array of `<Survey />` components and inside the Button component is the button *Next* and *Previous* which call the functions `next()` and `back()`. Inside the `<Survey />` component is just a few radio input field that are marked as required.

Comment: You can try to add type="button" to the button. Or you can try to add to the button key=something, something unique for each step.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the next button is submitting the form before the next component has had a chance to render. To prevent this, you can use the preventDefault() method on the next button to prevent the form from submitting. You can also use the ref attribute to get a reference to the form element and then call the reset() method on it to clear the form data before rendering the next component.

Here is an example of how to do this:

```
const Form = ({ statementArray, currentStepIndex, getNextStatement, next, back }) => {
  const formRef = useRef();

  return (
    <form ref={formRef}>
      {statementArray[currentStepIndex]}

      <Buttons
        currentStep={currentStepIndex}
        getNextStatement={getNextStatement}
        next={() => {
          next();
          formRef.current.reset();
        }}
        back={back}
      />
    </form>
  );
};
```

This will prevent the form from submitting before the next component has had a chance to render and will also clear the form data before rendering the next component.